# filter antd table according to its columns

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, antd

First of all english is not my mother language so there might be mistakes. I started react with hooks since everybody said its easier, here i have antd table and a button (bootstrap 5 modal), this modal contains 6 buttons (id, title, firstname, lastname, Choose all, confirm your selection), my point is user chooses from ID, Title, firstname, lastname, when user has chosen he clicks'Confirm your selections' then if he chose for example 'FirstName and LastName' then those other columns except these two gets deleted/display:none?? from table then again if he wants those columns back he choose 'Choose all or just select them' and click 'confirm your selection'. Been looking from antd site but they didnt have that, any suggestions?

here my code:

```js
function EventsSection() {
  const eventsData = [
    {
      key: 1,
      title: "Bulletproof EP1",
      firstName: "james",
      lastName: "cordon",
    },
  ];

  console.log(eventsData);

  return (
    <section>
      <EventsTable eventsData={eventsData} />
      <span
        className="material-icons"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
      >
        button
      </span>

      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModal"
        // tabIndex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header ">
              <h1 className="modal-title " id="exampleModalLabel">
                Filter table{" "}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body ">
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  ID{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Title{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                {" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  FirstName{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                {" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  LastName
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                {" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Choose All{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                {" "}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  confirm your selections{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default EventsSection;
```

```js
const EventsTable = ({ eventsData }) => {
  const tableColumns = [
    {
      title: "ID",
      dataIndex: "key",
      key: "id",
    },
    {
      title: "Title",
      dataIndex: "title",
      key: "title",
    },
    {
      title: "FirstName",
      dataIndex: "firstName",
      key: "firstName",
    },
    {
      title: "LastName",
      dataIndex: "lastName",
      key: "lastName",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table dataSource={eventsData} columns={tableColumns} pagination={false} />
  );
};

export { EventsTable };
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you recreate the scenario at StackBlitz or CodeSandbox?

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar the point is i have not found anywhere similar, and dont know have to create example, but it is easy to understand, choose from buttons inside a modal and display:none those others except what has been chosen

Comment: I understood your question. But I said if you could just upload your work at StackBlitz or CodeSandbox.

Comment: good that my question was clear, the picture above is what i have done and there is also codes, but that particular of doing this is what i have been looking for(dont know the way of putting classes for example to antd column)

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar would appreciate if you have time and could possibly help with this

Comment: I'll try my best.

Comment: here if it helps :  https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-ellis-zw759?file=/src/EventsSection.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented what you wanted at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-allen-h7bd6).

I've implemented checkbox selection instead of button selection, which feels more convenient.

**Demo:** [image]

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted !

Comment: the functionality is great !

Comment: Done. Check at https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-allen-h7bd6?file=/src/EventsSection.js

Comment: its not working for me, im not getting any error in my project but its not filtering

Comment: Please follow the new implementation where you don't need to write a checkbox for each column. It's dynamic now. https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-allen-h7bd6?file=/src/EventsSection.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230420/discussion-between-zunayed-shahriar-and-walee).

Comment: code works without this :  useEffect(() => {
    setIndeterminate(
      !!checkedList.length && checkedList.length < allColumnKeys.length
    );
    setCheckAll(checkedList.length === allColumnKeys.length);

    return () => {};
  }, [checkedList]);, what is it for ?

Comment: Code will work. But it is for the all selection checkbox. It'll set the state of the all select checkbox. So, if all items are checked then it will also be checked, when some of the items are checked then it will be indeterminate and if none of the items are checked then it will also be unchecked.

Comment: added to discussion

Comment: Brother could you possibly add those buttons 'Delivered,In Delivery, Order' inside a modal (from it user could see which one he/she has chosen) like there is another modal called 'Filter', that would help

Comment: I don't understand. Show me an image or sketch of what you want to do.

Comment: this is image of what i want from that other filter :         https://imgur.com/LaUQfl6